# Best way to call multiple operations multiple times after another

Tags: c#, web-scraping, design-patterns

I have the following scenario:

there are 3 API's that I call every 5 minutes. I do this asynchronously so the order of calling the `API` doesn't matter. A 'call' itself contains

1. A `HTTP`-request to the `API`
2. The extraction of data (reading the response)
3. Storing it into a Database.

so these 3 steps are always the same. Currently my code looks somewhat like this:

```
scraper.Request()
scraper.Extract()
scraper.Save()
```

I surely put that into another function to wrap it up but it somehow looks weird to me. Are there any 'Patterns' I could follow, that match my scenario?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: pattern? the pattern is "when there's some common logic that needs to be called multiple times, extract a method for it and call that multiple times.From my perspective there's nothing to be done here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do the same thing three times, encapsulate it in a method and call the method three times passing in an appropriate parameter each time. Maybe something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    PollApi("http://firstapi.com");
    PollApi("http://api.second.com");
    PollApi("http://wkdapis.com/third");
}

private void PollApi(string url)
{
    scraper.Request(url);
    scraper.Extract();
    scraper.Save();
}
```

I presume you already have something in place to time the calls five minutes apart...